# Parametric smooth curve that vists all integer points of the plane

Tags: curves

> Does there exist a parametric smooth curve that visits all integer points $(x,y),\, x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ of the plane?

Something similar to this:

$$\begin{align}
x = &\theta \cos(2\sin(\theta\pi))\\
y = &\theta \sin(\theta\pi)\end{align}$$

see the [plot on Fooplot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4Ijoicypjb3MoMipzaW4ocypwaSkpIiwiZXF5IjoicypzaW4ocypwaSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNmZjAwMDAiLCJzbWluIjoiMCIsInNtYXgiOiI0cGkiLCJzc3RlcCI6Ii4wMSJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMCwid2luZG93IjpbIi0xOS44MzY0MjU3ODEyNDk5OSIsIjE5LjgzNjQyNTc4MTI0OTk5IiwiLTEyLjIwNzAzMTI0OTk5OTk5NSIsIjEyLjIwNzAzMTI0OTk5OTk5NSJdfV0-) ... a sort of (inverted) *smooth* Cantor pairing function.

Or can it be proven that such a curve cannot exist?

I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1495063/9020) this question on math.stackexchange last week, but didn't get a satisfactory answer: the curve suggested in the answer is the inverse Cantor's pairing function, so it uses the *floor* and I would like to know if floor/ceil can be avoided.

Comment: I think it is clear that what you want is not what you are asking for (and hence the votes to close).  @BjørnKjos-Hanssen answered your question as asked.  If you changed smooth to analytic (as Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen suggested in a comment below), one could still possibly describe such an analytic function by giving something other than a formula.  I think what you are looking for is a formula using only the type of continuous functions found in a calculus book (and no piece-wise functions).  However, such a question is very difficult since that class of functions is fairly ad-hoc.

Comment: Having said that, I think the analytic question is interesting.  If you do ask that, ask it in a separate question and don't reject an answer just because it is not of the form you were hoping for.

Comment: Perhaps a better question could be "is there a pair of real analytic functions such that $(x(t),y(t))$ visits all integer points in the plane?"  Or even "is there a holmorphic function (in a neighborhood of the real axis) such that the image of the real axis contains all Gauss integers?"

Comment: @JasonRute: These new versions of the question are still trivial. An entire function can take any desired values on any discrete set. See for example my very first MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161473/why-is-there-no-connection-between-fast-growing-functions-and-complex-analysis/161670#161670

Comment: @ChristianRemling, I stand corrected.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I'm not an expert, can you give me an example of a trivial function that is parametric, smooth, doesn't use floor/ceil, is not constructed by case analysis or joining together distinct pieces and visits all the integers points (x,y) x,y>=0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Start with a compact smooth "bump" curve
$$\mathbf r(t)=\langle x(t),y(t)\rangle,\qquad 0\le t\le 1$$
with
$$x^{(n)}(0)=y^{(n)}(1)=0\qquad\text{for all }n,$$
$\mathbf r(0)=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and
$\mathbf r(1)=\langle 0,1\rangle$.

Then by rotating and translating it, and using straight line segments as well, you can stitch together your smooth function as follows.

[image]
(Bump curve shown in blue.)

Comment: But is it definiable using a compact parametric representation ($x=f(\theta), y=g(\theta)$)?

Comment: @Marzio De Biasi: what is the definition of "compact parametric representation"?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: sorry for the bad terminology; in this answer Bjorn uses $t$, $n$ and $r$ and it is unclear for me if they can be considered as ONE parameter... what I would like to know is if such a curve can be epxressed as $( f(\theta), g(\theta) ),\;  \theta \geq 0$ in which $f,g$ are smooth (i.e. continuously differentiable) .... so floor/ceil are not allowed, and also using extra parameters "over closed intervals" is not allowed. Apparently it seems an easy question (4 close votes at the moment), but I'm not able to figure it out ... or I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Marzio De Biasi Yes there's only one parameter, $t $. Note  that  a function defined by cases can still be smooth. OTOH if you had asked for *analytic* functions it  becomes harder.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: ok I realize that I should have specified to also avoid definitions by case  ... perhaps analytic is the key term ?!?

Comment: Actually, @BjørnKjos-Hanssen, I don't think this is exactly what you or the OP wants. You don't want $\mathbf{r}'(t)=0$ else the curve can have corners and cusps---even though yours does not.  Instead, I think you can modify your bump to have $\mathbf{r}'(0) = \langle 0, -1 \rangle$ and $\mathbf{r}'(1) = \langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\mathbf{r}'(t) \neq \mathbf{0}$.  (I guess this all comes down to the definition of *smooth*--which often seems to be given as "enough continuous derivatives" and also as "no corners", even those these are not the same thing.)

Comment: Nevermind.  I can't read.  (I saw the $x$ and $y$ as a $\mathbf{r}$ for some reason.  Now this makes sense.)